# What the best way to display html in the recyclerView?

Tags: android, html, css, android-recyclerview, spannable

In the recyclerView I display comments. Comments are stored as HTML.

I tried to display the comments in webView - all displayed well (with the ability to use custom *.css) but recyclerView significantly retarding while scrolling. And I was not able to make it "transparent" to the touch, because commentView support ripple effect (android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground") but webView - no.

Also I tried to display the comments in textView as spannable. Everything works fast but much more difficult to customize the appearance.

Help me to choose the best way to display the comments in recyclerView.

As a result I want to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here htmlString will is holding you html content.

`TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_string);
 textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));`